# Render multivalued Multimedia Component link with metadata in DWT

Tags: templating, dwt, componentpresentation

I have Component with multivalued Multimedia Component link field named "list". Each Multimedia Component has its own metadata ("thumbnail" and "altText"). I need to write a DWT TBB to extract those metadata values. I am using DGX in templating.

I tried this code but its rendering the image not metadatas.

```html
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="list" -->                                    
<div>
<a href="@@Get("Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Id.Metadata.thumbnail")@@">
<img alt="@@Get("Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Id.Metadata.altText")@@" src="@@Get("Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Id")@@"/>
</a>
</div>
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Answer (score 4):

`Id` is a property of the linked component, not a reference to the component itself - You already have that with

```
Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}]
```

Try removing the Id from your `href` and `alt` attributes.

```html
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="list" -->                                    
<div>
<a href="@@Get("Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Metadata.thumbnail")@@">
<img alt="@@Get("Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Metadata.altText")@@" src="@@Get("Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Id")@@"/>
</a>
</div>
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

In fact, if you look at the samples on the [Dreamweaver Get eXtension](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/dreamweaver_get_extension.aspx) page on SDL Tridion World, it looks like Id is returned by default, so you can probably remove it from your `src` attribute also, like this:

```html
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="list" -->                                    
<div>
<a href="@@Get("Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Metadata.thumbnail")@@">
<img alt="@@Get("Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}].Metadata.altText")@@" src="@@Get("Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}]")@@"/>
</a>
</div>
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Comment: Syntax for DGX can be found here: https://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/dreamweaver_get_extension.aspx

Comment: I used that as well but it shows "undefined" for that particular field

Comment: I think Davids code should work, but you could also try `@@GetFromItem(Fields.list[${TemplateRepeatIndex}], "Metadata.altText")@@`